# Программа переводит текст с русского на английский. Затем записывает их в базу данных sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

Сначала она переводила без добавления слов в базу данных.
Когда я создал базу данных питон начал есть оперативку.
За 5 минут с 200mb до 1.5gb
В чем проблема? Почему так?
Ссылка на код:
https://github.com/kiselevdv90/translator/blob/main/translator.py

```
from googletrans import Translator
from gtts import gTTS
from playsound import playsound
import os
import sqlite3

translator = sqlite3.connect('vocabulary.db')
data = translator.cursor()
data.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vocabulary (
    Word_en TEXT,
    Word_ru TEXT)''')
translator.commit()

while True :
    #ОСТАНОВКА ЦИКЛА    
    Word_ru = input('Введите текст: ')
    if Word_ru == 'все':
        break

    # Переводит с русского на английский
    translator = Translator()
    Word_en = translator.translate(Word_ru, dest='en')
    Word_en = Word_en.text
    print(Word_en)


    # ОЗВУЧИВАНИЕ ТЕКСТА
    tts = gTTS(Word_en)
    tts.save('hello.mp3')
    playsound('hello.mp3')
    os.remove('hello.mp3')

    #ЗАПИСЫВАЕТ СЛОВА В БАЗУ ДАННЫХ
    translator = sqlite3.connect('vocabulary.db')
    data = translator.cursor()
    data.execute('INSERT INTO vocabulary VALUES (?,?)', (Word_en, Word_ru))
    translator.commit()
    translator.close()
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей

Comment: А зачем вы там создаете на каждой итерации цикла по коннекту к базе, да еще и не закрываете потом?

Comment: если их убрать то он выдает ошибку 'Translator' object has no attribute 'commit'

Comment: У Вас под одной переменной и коннект к базе, и объект Translator. Для начала дайте разные названия